# Consolidate many if conditions to a single LINQ statement if possible

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, ef-code-first

I am currently using ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework Code First using the repository pattern to display a simple list of users that has paging. I am adding the ability to filter that list by allowing the end user to select conditions from two drop downs and two text boxes with start and end date.

Is there a better way to do this than the code below where I have to test for all possible combinations of parameters in order to write the appropriate LINQ query:

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetAllByCondition(int? condition1, int? condition2, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
{
    if (condition1.HasValue && startDate.HasValue && endDate.HasValue)
    {
        return Database.Set<User>().Where(x => x.Condition1 == condition1.Value && x.Date > startDate.Value && x.Date <= endDate.Value).ToList();
    }

    if (condition1.HasValue && condition2.HasValue)
    {
        return Database.Set<User>().Where(x => x.Condition1 == condition1.Value && x.Condition2 == condition2.Value).ToList();
    }

    if (condition1.HasValue)
    {
        return Database.Set<User>().Where(x => x.Condition1 == condition1.Value).ToList();
    }

    .... and the list goes on
}
```

This can quickly get bloated if I add one one more condition in the future.

Comment: in your code if condition1.HasValue is true only first if statement execute otherwise none of if statement not executed, why write this code?

Comment: It was just to illustrate a point. I edited it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the fact that queries compose - you can just keep calling `Where` to add more conditions:

```
var query = Database.Set<User>();

if (condition1.HasValue)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Condition1 == condition1.Value);
}
if (condition2.HasValue)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Condition2 == condition2.Value);
}
...
return query.ToList();
```

Comment: +1. This is so marvelous - use it for months now. THis is the real marvel of LINQ - no test appending and efficient queiris without superflous conditions.

Comment: Thanks Jon, but isn't this very similar to my example. I think your example reads better but I was trying to see if there is a way to take it a step further and move away from all the if statements. I am not even sure if it is possible but worth the question.

Comment: Jon Skeet's example not only reads better, but it works for all combinations of conditions with just one if-statement per condition. Your approach will require a lot more if-statements. (+1 for Jon Skeet)

Comment: Jon, this would append to the query using an AND statement. How would I go about appending to the query using an OR statement instead?

Comment: @Thomas: You'd use `PredicateBuilder` - http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx